# How to merge woocommerce older version to newer one?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have woocommerce plugin installed in my ecommerce website. I have made some custom changes in some of file of woocommerce plugin. Now i want to update my woocommerce plugin. If i do by clicking on button update now then i will lose my custom changes which i made. I want to update woocommerce plugin without loosing my custom changes. So what is the best to merge all the changes to newer version and to update woocommerce plugin . is there any way to update woocommerce plugin manually so custom changes still remain there.

Answer (score 0):

As you know its a bad idea having to edit plugin files because of updates.. if the plugin in question uses hooks you can write your own plugin that has your own custom code for that plugin. Here a  post that might help you wrap your head around it. https://iandunn.name/2014/01/10/the-right-way-to-customize-a-wordpress-plugin/